# Suspicious CPU activity when computer wakes from sleep; VPN suspected?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, malware, cpu-usage

Recently I noticed that upon waking from sleep, one or more of my CPU cores were running at full blast. My computer sleeps without fans on, so this is worrisome to say the least.

I have experienced this before with bitcoin mining malware. The malware was found and successfully removed, and the activity stopped.

This time, it ONLY happens when my VPN client (I use NordVPN and the client is one downloaded from their site) is on and connected. Basically I wake it from sleep and the CPU is blasting away, with total CPU usage jumping from 50-75-100 percent. A quick look with Open Hardware Monitor shows cores running at full, and worrisome temps (though thankfully the i5 handles heat fairly well). I disconnect from the VPN and the CPU drop is instant. My computer rarely runs higher than 15% CPU usage under any circumstance where I can see the desktop.

So I emailed them about this. They asked for my log.txt file in the client directory. This was their response.

> Hello, ----,
>
> Thank you for your letter.
>
> It tends to happen because of the constant pinging of the VPN servers,
>   since we recently have added more servers, it tends to require more
>   memory to do so, however we are planning to refurbish our NordVPN
>   software for Windows very soon, and to eliminate such issues with the
>   new version of the software.
>
> In the meantime, you could try deleting the log.txt file from the
>   NordVPN software. Also alternatively you can set up a connection via
>   OpenVPN GUI software, it would be consuming less CPU while connected
>   to the VPN. You can find guide on how to set up connection via OpenVPN
>   GUI here: https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/windows-8/openvpn/

How can I tell if what they say about NordVPN pinging is true

Comment: Sounds like they are mining. I would like to know this too. Are there any processes with the NordVPN software that are showing in the cpu? or files they are pointing to?

Comment: Have you tried their suggestion?

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select "First Level", under  Resource select **CPU usage** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Standby/Resume**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This suspends the device and resumes it and captures the CPU activity. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: Thank you for very simple instructions... hope you are a good guy as apparently this file contains sensitive information...  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Qe-X2iAqhbTHBwRm5BaDJScjg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ok, I posted what I saw. Next time notify me with @ my username so that I see that you replied.

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at the trace with WPA.exe](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis), I see that the CPU usage comes from `mscorsvw.exe` (`.NET Runtime Optimization Service`) which optimizes [.net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) files to make .net programs (like your VPN tool - NordVPN Client.exe) faster.

Open a [command prompt as admin](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2790-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-10-a.html) in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\`

[image]

and run `ngen update` and wait until this is done before taking your device in sleep mode again.